# Почему не работает отправка? И как здесь реализовать цикл while True отдельно, чтобы не мешал работе программы

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3, while

```
@dp.message_handler(state=user_reg.send)
async def sending(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    while True:
        us_tm = get_time(id3)
        f = datetime.now()
        now_secs = f.second
        now_hours = f.hour
        now_mins = f.minute
        us_secs = int(us_tm[6:8])
        us_mins = int(us_tm[3:5])
        us_hours = int(us_tm[0:2])
        if now_secs == us_secs:
            if now_hours == us_hours:
                if now_mins == us_mins:
                    currency = get_currency(id3)
                    global url
                    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={currency}+rub'
                    global headers
                    headers = {
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
                    currency_1 = get_currency_price()
                    await bot.send_message(id3, f"<b>Курс валюты на данный момент:</b>\n"
                                                            f"{currency_1} рублей", parse_mode='html')









@dp.message_handler(state=user_reg.reg_time)
async def reg_time(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    await state.finish()
    global id3
    add_time(message)
    id3 = get_user_id(message)
    status = add_time(message)
    us_tm = get_time(chat_id)
    if status == False:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Неверное время!")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Успешно добавлено время отправки:\n"
                                        f"<b>{us_tm}</b>", parse_mode='html')
        await user_reg.send.set()
```

Сделал так, чтобы переменная с айди была глобальной, но если я перед отправкой ничего не отправлю боту - мне ничего не придет, значит логично что дело в айди.